Help Identifying wall texture
I thought this wall texture might be a light stomp but it doesn't look anything like the ceiling stomp. It almost looks like they used a roller over wet mud.

That looks like an orange-peel with multiple coats of paint over it.
If you need to match it, try to spray on a heavy coat of orange-peel, followed by a lighter coat.  Always spray in a circular motion always moving.

What about this one?
